# Python numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

hi im trying to rotate an image 90 degree's but i keeep getting this error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence" and im not sure whats the problem.

when i try and run the function with an array it works, but when i try it with an image i get that error.

```
def rotate_by_90_deg(im):
    new_mat=np.zeros((im.shape[1],im.shape[0]),  dtype=np.uint8)
    n = im.shape[0]
    for x in  range(im.shape[0]):
        for y in range(im.shape[1]):
            new_mat[y,n-1-x]=im[x,y]
    return new_mat
    pass
```

Comment: Whan to use [`np.rot90`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html)?

Comment: Your image might be stored in a way that im[x,y] returns an array with 1 element instead of the element itself. ([0] instead of 0). This is only a possibility, of course, but you can easily check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the error message with this code:

```
import numpy as np
def rotate_by_90_deg(im):
    new_mat=np.zeros((im.shape[1],im.shape[0]),  dtype=np.uint8)
    n = im.shape[0]
    for x in  range(im.shape[0]):
        for y in range(im.shape[1]):
            new_mat[y,n-1-x]=im[x,y]
    return new_mat

im = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
rotate_by_90_deg(im)
```

The problem here is that `im` is 3-dimensional, not 2-dimensional. That might happen if your image is in RGB format, for example.
So `im[x,y]` is an array of shape (3,). `new_mat[y, n-1-x]` expects a `np.uint8` value, but instead is getting assigned to an array.

---

To fix `rotate_by_90_deg`, make `new_mat` have the same number of axes as `im`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)

def rotate_by_90_deg(im):
    H, W, V = im.shape[0], im.shape[1], im.shape[2:]
    new_mat = np.empty((W, H)+V, dtype=im.dtype)
    n = im.shape[0]
    for x in  range(im.shape[0]):
        for y in range(im.shape[1]):
            new_mat[y,n-1-x]=im[x,y]
    return new_mat

im = np.random.random((3,3,3))
arr = rotate_by_90_deg(im)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].imshow(10*im, interpolation='nearest')
ax[0].set_title('orig')
ax[1].imshow(10*arr, interpolation='nearest')
ax[1].set_title('rot90')
plt.show()
```

### [image]

Or, you could use [`np.rot90`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)
im = np.random.random((3,3,3))
arr = np.rot90(im, 3)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].imshow(10*im, interpolation='nearest')
ax[0].set_title('orig')
ax[1].imshow(10*arr, interpolation='nearest')
ax[1].set_title('rot90')
plt.show()
```